# Spark Encoder for generic T with upper bound

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-sql

**How to work with a product encoder for a generic upper-bounded `Product` class?**

The following code doesn't compile:

```
class EnrichmentParser[VALUE <: KafkaValueContract](typeParser: TypeParser[VALUE]) extends Serializable {

  private def parseKey(row: Row): KafkaKeyContract = ...

  private def parseValue(row: Row): VALUE = typeParser.parse(row)

  private def parseRow(row: Row): KafkaMessage[KafkaKeyContract, VALUE] = {
    val key = parseKey(row)
    val value = parseValue(row)
    KafkaMessage(Some(key), value)
  }

  def parse(df: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    df.map(row => parseRow(row)).toDF()

  }
```

`KafkaValueContract` naturally extends `Product` so we can use it as a Dataset type:

```
abstract class KafkaValueContract(val metadata: Metadata,
                                  val changes: Changes) extends Product with Serializable
```

`VALUE` is whatever case class extending `KafkaValueContract`, for example:

```
case class PlaceholderDataContract(override val metadata: PlaceholderMetadata,
                                   override val changes: PlaceholderChanges) extends KafkaValueContract(metadata, changes)
```

However, the compiler complains that there is no encoder for `KafkaMessage[KafkaKeyContract, VALUE]`, which I expected to have since `VALUE` is any other (case) class that extends `KafkaValueContract` which in turn extends `Product`:

```
[error] ... KafkaMessage[KafkaKeyContract,VALUE]. An implicit Encoder[KafkaMessage[KafkaKeyContract,VALUE]] is needed to store KafkaMessage[KafkaKeyContract,VALUE] instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[error]     df.map(row => parseRow(row)).toDF()
[error]           ^
```

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

If I add `TypeTag` to the class signature in order to explicitly tell Scala that the class is concrete it finds the implicit product encoder:

```
class EnrichmentParser[VALUE <: KafkaValueContract : TypeTag](typeParser: TypeParser[VALUE]) extends Serializable {
```

However, it throws a reflection exception:

```
type _$1 is not a class
scala.ScalaReflectionException: type _$1 is not a class
```